# Add class on div mouse enter mouse leave and click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What i am trying to achieve is, i want to make it work like star rating. When you enter mouse star becomes yellow, when you leave mouse it turns gray and then if you click it again becomes yellow. 
  Not getting how to achieve it, I have added code to show you what i have tried so far.

**[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLxbw216/)**

```js
$(".na").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("clickstar");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("clickstar");
  }
);
$(".na").on("click",function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("clickstar");
});
```

```css
.clickstar{
  background: #00A1EF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="na" style="border:1px solid #c0c0c0;border-radius:50%;width:115px;height:115px;display:inline-table;margin-right:5px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(".na").on("click",function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("clickstar");
});
```

**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xLxbw216/5/)**

Comment: I guess he wants the clicked circle to go back to white when it's clicked twice.

Answer (score 3):

**You should consider using 2 different classes, `.hoverstar` and `.clickstar`, then :**

http://jsfiddle.net/xLxbw216/1/

*You would have one class for each case, which seems more logical ?*

**You can also make it simpler by removing .hover() method, and do it with CSS :**

http://jsfiddle.net/xLxbw216/8/

*I probably choose the second one, even if the first solution seems to be more "readable".*

Answer (score 1):

You should use a different class for permanent start and hover star

I have created a working example in [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLxbw216/9/)

```
$(".na").hover(
  function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      if (!$this.hasClass("permstar")) {
          $this.addClass("clickstar");
      }
  },
  function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      if (!$this.hasClass("permstar")) {
          $(this).removeClass("clickstar");
      }
  }
);
$(".na").on("click",function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("permstar");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

add/remove class on hover events was conflicting with on click event, so i have moved the hover functionality to css

**css:**

```
.clickstar{
background: #00A1EF;
}
.na:hover{
 background: #00A1EF;
}
```

**live demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/xLxbw216/7/

Happy Coding :)